# CSS splitting per page in Next.js

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, next.js

I need my css stylesheet split into many files, one per each Next.js page. How to implement this?

I tried to use `next-css` and just import a css-file into each page. It almost works. However the css-file is not loaded on Link navigation. Authors of Next say it's not implemented:
https://github.com/zeit/next-plugins/issues/282#issuecomment-523128645

I also tried using `styled-jsx`. It has several problems for me. It has many bugs on its Issues page. I also failed to make styles visible throughout child components with this approach.

Comment: Can you add a bit about your use case? Are you manually splitting the file or are you hoping to chunk it automatically based on the structure of each page? Or is it simply the linking that's an issue?

Comment: @BryceHowitson Any kind of solution would be helpful. Split in chunks based on what page imports what. And then ship correct styles together with pages on both SSR and Client page switch.

Comment: I guess I'm still not really understanding your question/problem. I'd suggest updating your question to help get answers. What does the app structure look like? Does a single CSS file work? Show us where/how you're linking or adding CSS now, etc.

Comment: @BryceHowitson The answers to these questions are already part of the solution. I just need to ship separate css-files one per each page. Page is the page in terms of Next.js.

Answer (score 2):

You can import a `module.css` (`import style from 'root/styles/MyStyle.module.css`) and use as follows.

This is your component:

```
import style from '../../styles/components/Header.module.css'

export default function Header() {
    return (
        <h1 className={style.header}>
            Hello World
        </h1>
    );
}
```

This is your CSS:

```
.header{
    color: #fff;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
}
```

Note that the CSS class is used as the components `className`;

Or, inside the react component, you can try adding the tag `<style jsx>{ your_CSS_here }</style>`.

According to Next documentation each page uses the [styled-jsx](https://github.com/vercel/styled-jsx) library. But you can still use other CSS-in-JS libraries such as [Styled Components](https://styled-components.com/) and [Emotion](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-emotion).

Next apps has also support for using [sass](https://sass-lang.com/) that allow you to import `.css` and `.scss` files.

For more information you can check the [Vercel Docs](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started). I also recommend you to check the [Learning area](https://nextjs.org/learn/basics/create-nextjs-app?utm_source=next-site&utm_medium=nav-cta&utm_campaign=next-website).

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently facing challenges with Next.js 13 due to the paradigm shift with server components, which prevents me from using CSS-in-JS like Styled Components. However, I'm exploring the use of CSS Modules. I'm sharing this here in case anyone has similar doubts. In the production build, they are indeed kept separate and are not bundled into a single file, which was a question I had. Furthermore, SCSS support in Next.js 13 is working well, with no additional configuration needed, which I'm not sure is the case in previous versions. I believe that just having SCSS support is a significant advantage.

Comment: Although this is relevant and useful information, it should be posted as a comment to the question. The reason for this advice is that this is not an answer in itself, but additional information related to the question.

Comment: I am currently in a similar position. I am using the new Next.js 13 `app` directory and due to some business usecases, my app can have one catch-all route.
From all the research that I have done, seems like the CSS modules splitting is done based on the routes only? Or am i wrong here? If I have a component imported dynamically based on some condition, will the CSS modules for that not be loaded if the condiditon isnt true? Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just remember analyzing this with the scss I mentioned and in development. but I think you can answer this by analyzing the css requests in devtools. the choice I mentioned was for a small project, a larger one with recent next.js I'm not up to date. TimeTerror; ok Sorry

Answer (score -1):

You can create your seperate css files and on each component that you need specific styling you import the css file that is unique to that component. so for example say you have a Component in file `file1.js` then you can import styles specific to this component in the file `file1.css` same happens for another file `file2` with css `file2.css`

```
import './file1.css'; //importing the style specific only for this component
function File1(){
      const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false)

    return (
        <> </>
    )
}
export default File1
```

Similarly for the second file

```
import './file2.css'; //css file specific to this component 
function File2(){
      const [processing, setProcessing] = useState(false)

    return (
        <> </>
    )
}
export default File2
```

Comment: I tried this. Css does not load on client-side page switch until you load it server-side at least once.

Comment: I see, Have you tried styled component. https://www.npmjs.com/package/styled-components

Comment: https://www.styled-components.com/docs/advanced#server-side-rendering